# getServerSideProps external api data fetching returns error

Tags: axios, next.js, fetch-api, getserversideprops

My http axios api data fetch attempt inside the  getServerSideProps function always returns error. I am succcessfully recovering token and userId from cockies, and trying to pass them as parameters to make server api call.

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {

        try {
        const { userId, token } = ctx.req.cookies; 
        // console.log(userId)      
        // console.log(token)               
           
            const res = await api.get(`/users/show/${userId}`, {
              headers: { token },
         
            })
          console.log(res.data)
            const userData  = res.data;      

          if (!userData) {
            return {
              notFound: true,
            }
          }
          
            return {
              props: {  
                userData
         
              }
            }
          
        } catch (error) {
          return error
        }
          
          
      }
```

And keep getting same error:

```js
  Server Error
Error: Additional keys were returned from `getServerSideProps`. Properties intended for your component must be nested under the `props` key, e.g.:

    return { props: { title: 'My Title', content: '...' } }

Keys that need to be moved: config, request, response, isAxiosError, toJSON.
```

Comment: return {
              notFound: true,
            }

to

return {
              props: {  
                notFound: true
         
              }
            }

Comment: What is this `await res.data; `

Comment: I added it  and same error continues

Comment: @Djony add `return { props: {} }` on catch block as well

Comment: @Chemi Adel It s already there !!!

Comment: `return error` is not same as `return { props: {} }` , you can't just return any object that's not wrapped between props

Answer (score 1):

The returned object should always be on way

> return { props: {//add your object here} }

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {

        try {
        const { userId, token } = ctx.req.cookies; 
        // console.log(userId)      
        // console.log(token)               
           
            const res = await api.get(`/users/show/${userId}`, {
              headers: { token },
         
            })
          console.log(res.data)
            const userData  = res.data;      

          if (!userData) {
            return {
              return { props: { notFound: true } },
            }
          }
          
            return {
              props: {  
                userData
         
              }
            }
          
        } catch (error) {
          return { props: {} }
        }
          
          
      }
```

Comment: OMG!!!! You got it !!!! Thanks sooo much!!  But now I got another prob, a typescript error related to id I am passing. I ll probably need to type tiken and id as string to pass them:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: @Djony Accepting the answer can helpful

Comment: I am still  stuck, with original problem, not sure if I am making api data fetching correctly, can t finding examples of axios api calls inside getServerSideProps. I am getting token and user id fromcockies and trying to pass as params, not working:      const res = await api.get<UserContextProps>(`/users/show/${userId}`, {
              params: { token },
              // or params:{
              //   userId
              // }
            })

Comment: I fixed it, it s fetching data, I just added some header basic configuration:          const res = await api.get<UserContextProps>(`/users/show/${userId}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
              }
            )